# Inno Setup change c:\ permission

Tags: window, inno-setup, acl

I have to set ACL of "C:\" folder (only this folder, not its subfolders!) to accept read/write from all users.
Is it possibile by Inno setup script?

Comment: To be more specific, by all users you mean the `Everyone` group ? And, are you creating that folder by your script (if so, there is the [`Permissions`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection&anchor=Permissions) parameter for that) ?

Comment: Yes, Everyone should be ok. Obviously "C:\" is not created by my app... :-) I could not use [Dir] Permissions because seems to be recurive to all subfolders (I don't want this).

Comment: Ok, I asked because I thought it is `c:\folder` in your question :-) And I forgot it's recursive.

Comment: xD sorry... I mean "C:\" folder.

Comment: Unless this is for an in-house (bespoke) app only, please do not even think about doing this sort of thing.  It's a security nightmare waiting for a PC to happen on.

Comment: This is a POS software that uses a third-part library that uses tmpnam() C++ function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/tmpnam/). This library make a temp file in c:\ (instead of %temp% path) and this is because i need to free C:\ for all user. I can not change that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `icacls.exe` from inno setup to set permissions

try to execute the following with the Exec or shellexec functions in the inno-setup

```
icacls "C:\" /grant Users:F
```

this might helpful, please check [icacls Information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: This looks like the most painless solution. I would suggest to use Windows API because you could get the result of that operation, but the first problem is that I don't know how (if there would be a C++ example, then maybe), and the second problem is that I don't know if all the Windows API functions needed for such operation are translateable in a hack-free way into InnoSetup. [+1]

Comment: Is this good also for XP? I agree with TLama... but i can not find any other solution