# Windows command to grant folder permission to SQL Server from Inno Setup

Tags: sql-server, windows, inno-setup

My Java application periodically bulk-inserts into SQL Server. So I will need to grant file system permission to SQL Server. I am able to do this manually. I wonder if there is a Windows command to grant permission to file system. I would like to use that in my Inno Setup file.

Comment: Try set-acl.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup has a built-in feature for changing permissions of directories, [`Permissions` parameters of `[Dirs]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection&anchor=Permissions):

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}"; Permissions: users-full
```

It will create the directory, if it does not exist yet.

See also [Inno Setup - How to set permissions of installation folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34717752/850848).

---

To answer your actual question: You can use `icacls`. See [Inno Setup change c:\ permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18330598/850848).