# Inno Setup Domain/Active Directory Rights

Tags: windows, permissions, installation, inno-setup

I don't see a default option on how to do this, but maybe with a `[Code]` section it is possible, but no clue where to start.

The problem:
Making a `[Dir]` entry with `everyone-modify` does give the `local-pc/everyone` group modify rights, as one would expect. However, users that log onto that local-pc with their domain or active directory account instead get defaulted to `<domain>/<usergroup>` with "read" rights. I want those users to also have modify rights. Another possibility would be, that anyone who can access the parent folder can modify this subfolder, which I hoped is what `everyone-modify` would do.

This issue exists on Windows 7, 10, Server 12, 16 and 19.
More might be affected, but that's all I tested.

Comment: The phrase "anyone who can access the parent folder" is too vague to be dictated programmatically.

Comment: The programmatic version of that phrase is "folder has no rights limitations"

Comment: What does "no rights limitations" mean? Do you mean you want to disable permission inheritance and allow everyone full control of the directory? (At least, I hope you don't mean that, from a security point of view.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking back in for future people who might find this. It turned out to be a bug in windows and got resolved with an update to it at least on Windows 10 / Server 16/19. As far as I know Win 7 is still broken, but we've stopped supporting it now.

Comment: What turned out to be a bug?

Comment: "All Users" is not all users, only all local users.

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup does not support granting permissions to a specific group. If you need to set different permissions than Inno Setup supports, you need to use an external application/command, like [`cacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cacls) or [`icacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls).

For examples, see:

- [Inno Setup - How to give one specific user rights to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54147843/850848)
- [Inno Setup change c:\ permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18330598/850848)

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what the user group is, as I'm just the application author, not the one running the environments.

Comment: OK, so maybe you should first ask a general question on [su], to find out, what you need to setup. And then come here to ask how to implement that in Inno Setup.

Comment: What would that question be? How find out what user group encompasses everyone even on network? I doubt that question has an answer.

Comment: If you do not think that this question has an answer, how do you expect Inno Setup to do it?